# Disable Weak TLS Cipher Suites on APIM

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I've just discovered few weak ciphers listed on a report I just ran:

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 256

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 128

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    256

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    128

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)   WEAK   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)   WEAK   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)   WEAK   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)   WEAK   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)   WEAK  256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)   WEAK  128

I only have these ciphers configured:

## TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS    256

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS    128

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 256

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK 128

TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp384r1 (eq. 7680 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    128

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)   WEAK   256

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)   WEAK   128

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)   WEAK   256

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)   WEAK   128

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)   WEAK  256

TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)   WEAK  128

Which ones from my list should be removed?

Note that top two only strong and reaming reported "weak" ciphers appear